# nil is not a symbol accepts_nested_attributes_for has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` working with a `has_one` association. I have the following set up using mongoid.

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars, inverse_of: nil
end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  has_one :magazine, class_name: 'Foo', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: nil
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :magazine
end
```

When I do the following in rails console I seem to get the following output.

```
r = Bar.new
=> #<Bar _id: 1213 .... 
[2] pry(main)> r.foo.build TypeError: nil is not a symbol from
/Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems
/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:155:in `respond_to?
```

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) is a good writeup of `inverse_of`.  Instead of `inverse_of: nil` in your models, you have to specify a symbol.  For example, the `:bars` association should be declared as `inverse_of: :magazine`.